# Spring & CloudAMQP on Heroku giving "Unknown Host Exception"

Tags: java, spring, heroku, rabbitmq, cloudamqp

I am trying to get Spring to work with CloudAMQP on the heroku platform.
This is my context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="#{systemEnvironment['CLOUDAMQP_URL']}"/>

    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        exchange="myExchange" routing-key="foo.bar"/>

    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

    <rabbit:queue name="myQueue" />

    <rabbit:topic-exchange name="myExchange">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="myQueue" pattern="foo.*" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:topic-exchange>


    <rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        error-handler="exHandler">

        <rabbit:listener ref="foo" method="listen" queue-names="myQueue" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>

    <bean id="foo" class="Foo" />
    <bean id="exHandler" class="BackgroundRejectingErrorHandler" />
</beans>
```

But I am running into something weird: Locally it works perfectly fine, passing CLOUDAMQP_URL=localhost, but on heroku I get the following exception:

```
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062653+00:00 app[worker.1]: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${HEROKU_CLOUDAMQP_URL}: invalid IPv6 address
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062655+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:71)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062655+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:367)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062656+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:565)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062659+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062660+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062661+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062661+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:336)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062662+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1136)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062663+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1387)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062664+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

where i replaced ${HEROKU_CLOUDAMQP_URL} with the actual connection string in form of:

```
amqp://$user:$password@HOST.cloudamqp.com/VHOST
```

Full stack trace:

```
2017-05-24T13:55:59.175707+00:00 app[worker.1]: INFO: Refreshing 
org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@65b3120a: startup date [Wed May 24 13:55:59 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-24T13:55:59.238539+00:00 app[worker.1]: May 24, 2017 1:55:59 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
2017-05-24T13:55:59.238556+00:00 app[worker.1]: INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [backgroundContext.xml]
2017-05-24T13:55:59.379090+00:00 app[worker.1]: May 24, 2017 1:55:59 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
2017-05-24T13:55:59.379102+00:00 app[worker.1]: INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [herokuApiBeans.xml]
2017-05-24T13:55:59.462609+00:00 app[worker.1]: May 24, 2017 1:55:59 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
2017-05-24T13:55:59.462612+00:00 app[worker.1]: INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [backgroundBeans.xml]
2017-05-24T13:55:59.570041+00:00 app[worker.1]: May 24, 2017 1:55:59 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
2017-05-24T13:55:59.570056+00:00 app[worker.1]: INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [rabbitMqConfig.xml]
2017-05-24T13:55:59.792582+00:00 app[worker.1]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
2017-05-24T13:55:59.792623+00:00 app[worker.1]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
2017-05-24T13:55:59.792726+00:00 app[worker.1]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2017-05-24T13:56:00.046847+00:00 app[worker.1]: May 24, 2017 1:56:00 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor start
2017-05-24T13:56:00.046865+00:00 app[worker.1]: INFO: Starting beans in phase -2147482648
2017-05-24T13:56:00.047727+00:00 app[worker.1]: May 24, 2017 1:56:00 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor start
2017-05-24T13:56:00.047728+00:00 app[worker.1]: INFO: Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062649+00:00 app[worker.1]: May 24, 2017 1:56:00 PM org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer redeclareElementsIfNecessary
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062652+00:00 app[worker.1]: SEVERE: Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062653+00:00 app[worker.1]: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${HEROKU_CLOUDAMQP_URL}: invalid IPv6 address
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062655+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:71)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062655+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:367)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062656+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:565)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062659+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062660+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062661+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062661+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:336)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062662+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1136)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062663+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1387)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062664+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062665+00:00 app[worker.1]: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${HEROKU_CLOUDAMQP_URL}: invalid IPv6 address
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062665+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1169)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062666+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062667+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at com.rabbitmq.client.DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.resolveIpAddresses(DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.java:83)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062668+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at com.rabbitmq.client.DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.getAddresses(DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.java:73)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062669+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:903)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062670+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062670+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1000)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062671+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:355)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062672+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ... 8 more
2017-05-24T13:56:00.062673+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2017-05-24T13:56:00.073827+00:00 app[worker.1]: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${HEROKU_CLOUDAMQP_URL}: invalid IPv6 address
2017-05-24T13:56:00.073937+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:71)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.074010+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:367)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.074139+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:565)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.074197+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.074258+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.074345+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:712)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.074396+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:780)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.074457+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:752)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.074525+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at background.ApplicationContextBackground.main(ApplicationContextBackground.java:45)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.074632+00:00 app[worker.1]: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${HEROKU_CLOUDAMQP_URL}: invalid IPv6 address
2017-05-24T13:56:00.074687+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1169)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.074738+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.074795+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at com.rabbitmq.client.DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.resolveIpAddresses(DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.java:83)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.074842+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at com.rabbitmq.client.DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.getAddresses(DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.java:73)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.074901+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:903)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.074953+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.075016+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1000)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.075092+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:355)
2017-05-24T13:56:00.075159+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ... 7 more
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it.

Obviously the rabbit:connection-factory ->HOST<- can not handle a complete uri.
So one has to split up all the parameters and pass them one after another.